Detecting a PL sphere and decompositions
Question 1. A PL $n$-sphere is a pure simplicial complex that is a triangulation of the $n$-sphere. I'm looking for a computer algorithm that gives a Yes/No answer to whether a given simplicial complex is a PL sphere. Does anyone know of this?
Question 2. I am also looking for an algorithm that finds a wedge-sum decomposition $K = K_1 \vee K_2$ of a given simplicial complex $K$. I am happy to assume that $K$ is a flag complex, meaning that $K$ is the maximal simplicial complex among other simplicial complexes sharing the 1-skeleton of $K$.
Question 3. Similarly to Question 2, I am interested in other algorithms that attempts to find decompositions like $K = K_1 * K_2$ (join), $K = K_1 \wedge K_2$ (smash product), $K = K_1 \times K_2$ (Cartesian product).
Remark. There are several bottlenecks to investigations such as the above. Recognising whether a given 3-dimensional simplicial complex is collapsible is NP-complete (Tancer 2015). Enumerating PL $n$-spheres with at most $n+4$ vertices takes GPU to work out for $n \le 11$ (Choi-Jang-Vallee 2024). I am attempting this with a beginner's adventurous spirit, so I'm happy to learn more about anything related.

This might be undecidable because it is already undecidable whether a finitely presented group is trivial (and the simplicial complex gives you a finite presentation of its $\pi_1$). I'm just not sure whether one can build homology spheres whose $\pi_1$ is undecidably trivial (that would tell you that your problem is undecidable).

@AchimKrause: A necessary and sufficient condition for a finitely presentable group to be the fundamental group of a homology sphere is for it to have vanishing $H_1$ and $H_2$.  See Kervaire’s paper “Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups”.  I assume that you can’t solve the triviality problem for groups with vanishing $H_2$, but I don’t know for certain.

I definitively heard a talk one explaining that it is possible to construct homology spheres with undeciably trivial $\pi_1$. Googling gave me the answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/98617/3969

In questions 2 and 3, what is the meaning of “equals”? Do you mean homeomorphic? Do you mean isomorphic as simplical complexes? For example, the product of a pair of intervals is a square - this does not have a “canonical” realisation as a simplical complex.

@Andy: You only need one missing ingredient: the universal central extension of a perfect group $G$ has $H_2=0$, and can be written down algorithmically from a finite presentation for $G$. (Cf. §3.2 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117 .) Combined with Kervaire's theorem and the Adyan--Rabin theorem, it follows that $n$-spheres are not recognisable for $n\geq 5$.

@HJRW: Ah, that’s a nice trick!

@SamNead, I want the equality to be either a homeomorphism or a homotopy equivalence.

A couple of small comments. Detecting $K=K_1\vee K_1$ up to isomorphism or homeomorphism is the same as detecting if removing a vertex (and all cofaces) separates $K$ into two connected components, right? This should be easy to check (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78014/algorithm-to-determine-which-vertices-edges-would-disconnect-undirected-graph-if).

When detecting $K\simeq K_1 \vee K_2$, $K_1 \simeq K_1 * K_2$, or $K\simeq K_1 \times K_2$ up to homotopy type, you probably want to assume that neither $K_1$ nor $K_2$ are contractible. This is since wedge summing, joining, or taking the product with a contractible space does not change the homotopy type.

The answer by Neil Strickland at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421046/is-the-decomposition-of-the-homotopy-type-of-a-complex-into-a-product-and-into-a seems to imply that decompositions into smash products $K \simeq K_1 \wedge K_2$ up to homotopy type will not be unique. Indeed, using his notation, $^/ \wedge ^/$ is contractible for any coprime integers $p$ and $q$.

To answer question 1:

There are fast (and easy to implement) algorithms to recognize the zero-, one-, and two-dimensional spheres.
Recognising the three-sphere is fast in practice. An algorithm to do this is implemented in the program Regina, written by Burton.  The problem is known to lie in NP (Schleimer, Ivanov) and co-NP (Lackenby).
The problem of recognizing the four-sphere is open.  Also, this problem feels uncomfortably close to the smooth Poincaré conjecture.
The problem of recognizing the five-sphere (or any sphere in higher dimensions) is undecidable.

Discussion of the state-of-the-art in dimensions four and higher can be found here.
